# Simplified ways to export gtsummary tables into Word

Tags: gtsummary

Does anyone have any simplified ways of exporting gtsummary tables into Word?

I am a novice R user and really like how efficiently gtsummary is able to produce publication ready tables. The only stumbling block I'm having now is how to easily export gtsummary's tables into Word documents to share with my colleagues that primarily use Word. I've tried the suggested method of exported gtsummary tables as a flex_tables and then further exporting those flex_tables as Word documents but that seemed to loose some of gtsummary’s nice formatting when I did so (perhaps I might get better results with more experience as other bloggers seemed to indicate they've gotten pretty good results by adding their own formatting scripts when exporting). I've also tried simply copying and pasting gtsummary’s html output into Word which was easy but which also caused me to lose some of gtsummary’s nice formatting.

Does anyone else have some suggested export solutions which have worked well for them?

Answer (score 7):

In the last release of gt (v0.9.0), Word output is fully supported. I would convert the gtsummary table to gt with `as_gt()`, then save it with `gt::gtsave()`. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'
packageVersion("gt")
#> [1] '0.9.0'


tf <- tempfile("example", fileext = ".docx")

trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt, 
    missing = "no",
    include = c(age, response)
  ) |> 
  add_difference() |> 
  as_gt() |> 
  gt::gtsave(filename = tf)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's wonderful, Mr. Sjoberg! I'm currently using R on a server with a much older of version of R, and Posit Cloud's gt package is only 0.8, so will see if my work will allow me to install a newer version of R on my computer that can run gt 0.8 so can take advantage of that new feature.

Comment: You could look into using renv to isolate your project from the system R package library. Then you'll be free to install any package you want into your project folder.

Comment: P.S., I tried out the gt::gtsave method. Works well but still seems to alter some of gt summaries formatting. E.g., after creating tbl_summary(mtcars), the gt::gtsave method adds extra horizontal lines around the header and each of the rows (as appears also in Mr. Sjoberg's above example). Using the gt::gtsave method also added a lot of additional white space between the variable and the results in the Word gt_summary table (as compared to the original tbl_summary(mtcars) object produced in gtsummary). I think I'll stick with html/pdf/word method when I want the highest fidelity copy.  Thx!

Answer (score 3):

I just do the analysis in `Rmarkdown` and save the knit the markdown document as a word document. You get excellent results. The tables looks exactly like they do in R.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I came up with that did seem to work well was:

1.save gtsummary’s html output as a pdf (many browsers can do so)
2.import the saved pdf into Adobe Acrobat
3.export the pdf that imported into Adobe Acrobat to Word using Adobe Acrobat’s “export” function

That method seemed to work pretty well. The gtsummary formatting seemed to be preserved although the process seemed to sometimes subtly change font types. However, once the gtsummary table was imported into Word by this method, I was able to edit the gtsummary table easily inside Word and change any font types as needed.

I’ll test this method out some more to see if there are any downsides to using this method but wanted to pass it on to others in case they hadn’t yet tried this method and wanted a simplified solution to export their gtsummary tables into word.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).